# Issue using saveRDS() with raster objects

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to use `saveRDS()` to save a large number of lists each containing a raster layer and a list with metadata. It worked fine when the raster layer was extracted from a ncdf file, but when the original file is an ascii file, `saveRDS()` only writes a pointer to the original file instead of writing the values to the end file.

Here's a condensed version of what's going on:

```
require(raster)

mf <- raster('myfile.asc')
meta <- list(mylonglistofmetadata)
res <- list(mf, meta)
saveRDS(res, 'myresult.Rdata')
```

`myresult.Rdata` is now simply a 33KB pointer to `myfile.asc`, when I really would like it to store the values so it will still work after I erase `myfile.asc` (so it should be about 15MB)

In contrast, for other files in ncdf format:

```
require(ncdf4)
require(raster)

ff <- 'myfile2.nc'
nc <- nc_open(ff)
meta <- list(mylonglistofmetadata)
res <- list(nc, meta)
saveRDS(res, 'myresult2.Rdata')
```

Here, `myresult2.Rdata` is storing everything just like I want it to, so my guess is that the issue arises with the raster package?

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this? I would prefer not to use `writeRaster()`, since I'm trying to keep the metadata together with the data, and use the same format as in my batch extracted from ncdf files to ease later processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can do:

```
mf <- raster('myfile.asc')
mf <- readAll(mf)
mf
```

Now, the values are in memory and will be saved to the .RData file

Also note that:

- You can save metadata with the data via writeRaster (see ?raster::metadata
- you can access ncdf files (with geographic data) via `raster('myfile2.nc')`
- your example for the ncdf file is not informative, as you do not actually use `nc` for anything. If you replaced `mf` with `nc` it would not work either after you removed `'myfile2.nc'`

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I replaced mf with nc in the example (that was a typo, sorry). I see now though that the reason it was working in my full code running with nc_open() is that I was using ncvar_get() to read the values and assign them to an empty raster, so basically doing the job of readAll()